# Where does the "original magnetism" come from?

Tags: electromagnetism

As we know, over time, magnets degrade in their magnetic flux density (for reasons I assume irrelevant to this question).

So I ask:

- What **first** gave iron the magnetising effect?

I emphasise "first" here: go back to the time when the planet was first being formed and, over time, the big molten-iron pool we are all rather fond of began forming as our core. Yes it is magnetic and this is undisputed and so too that it's magnetism is decaying (slowly...) but for the magnetism to decay it must have once had a "full" magnetism (to explain this better: think of half-lives; a particle which loses half its mass every week would, from the moment of instantiation, be at 100% mass and by next week be 50% mass: I assume that so too should a magnet once be at 100% magnetism)

Also, assuming we live in the future and can splice sub-atomic particles together; if we were to create a substance with a similar atomic structure to that of iron, would it be magnetic? Would it instantly lose its magnetic property on the altering of its sub-atomic structure?

Thanks for any feedback, this has been picking away at my mind for too long! :)

Comment: I suggest you take a look at the [Wikipedia article on Ferromagnetism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ferromagnetism).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ferromagnetism comes from the alignment of magnetic moments (spins). Each electron has a spin which is a micro magnet. They can be aligned or disaligned. If they align, they create a macroscopic magnet.

Thermal fluctuations disturb the alignment of the spins. So above a certain temperature, the ferromagnetism breaks down.

Magnets form when iron is cooled down. Small perturbations will cause blocks of the iron to align their spins and that creates ferromagnets. Those are then frozen in as the iron cools, a ferromagnet is created.

Comment: Ferromagnetism is due to electron spin, not nucleon magnetic moment.

Comment: @ Martin Ueding - Ferromagnetism is NOT due to the magnetic dipole moments if the NUCLEONS! Ferromagnetism is due to the alignment of the spins and thus magnetic dipole moments of  ELECTRONS in the electron shells of neighboring  atoms in the crystal lattice of a ferromagnetic material!

Comment: Oh, thanks for pointing it out! I did not think about the inverse mass in the magnetic moment. I updated my answer.